# Is there a way to use a variable as the email address in a php mail() function

Tags: php, string, email, variables, object

I'm trying to get an email to mail to a variable.

My code is as follows:

```
 mail($email, 'Order Confirmation', $body);
```

It comes up with the error message:

```
 mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

I have tried using `print_r` as suggested elsewhere on the web but it doesn't work. Is there a way to convert an object to a string?

**ANSWERED**It was caused by me using an array from a mysql database further up the code. Adding a while loop around the mail sorted the issue.

Comment: Use echo var_dump() instead of print_r, then put the output in your question

Comment: var_dump gives the following output

Comment: You can cast the variable as a string — `(string)$email`. But I would try to figure out why `$email` is an object in the first place?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#2 (0) { }

Comment: mysqli_result is an object, not a string, and moreover it's a result object so you need to understand what makes up that object. Please refer to the mysqli documentat on how to do this.

Comment: @user3123891: `$email` **must** be a string. Now it's a MySQL result object. You need to use functions like `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` (if you're using MySQLi) to get the actual email.

Answer (score 1):

just use this example

```
     <?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: upvote, but while correct I'd like to see what he's getting wrong exactly so we can help with that too :)

Comment: Yeah, I had posted that before he ever posted his output.

Comment: what is the next problem?

Comment: The fact he's trying to pass in a mysqli result object, it's in his comments.

Comment: I didnt getting enough info from his comment about that.

Comment: @user3123891- you should accept this as your answer if you found this answer is useful, it will help others who are browsing this similar type questions. If not comment under this answer....

Comment: Agreed, this has been around for a while

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? You should consider reading the manual here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$to      = 'stackoverflow@example.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```